# Is it valid to average IQR values?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, dispersion, interquartile

I am interested in quantifying the dispersion of pixel values in one image. More specifically, I want to get an average value of dispersion of the image column-wise (i.e., compute the dispersion of each column of the image and then "average" these values).

Currently, I am using two different metrics: SD and IQR. Regarding the former, the proper way to do so is to [average the variances of each column and then take the square root](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25848/how-to-sum-a-standard-deviation). Is there such particular consideration that should be taken into account for IQR or is it valid to just take the average of the IQR values?

Comment: Never seen a mean IQR before, but in principle it sounds just another  particular application of the mean.  Wherever I want to use the IQR I am usually troubled by long or fat tails in the raw data and the IQR gives me some resistance already. As a matter of style rather than substance I think I'd expect to see median IQR as well as, if not in preference to, mean IQR. Naturally, if they agree, your position is strengthened.

Comment: Originally I wanted to use the mean in order to keep it consistent with the SD case. However, what you say indeed makes sense. If there is no reason _not_ to use the mean, I will just report both (mean and median)

Comment: What is this mean intended to represent? What does it tell you?